# What is the user_id parameter of Wordpress function "wp_check_password" used for

Tags: wordpress

I checked the wordpress documents for function:

```
wp_check_password( string $password, string $hash, string|int $user_id = '' )
```

and cannot figure out what is the purpose for `$user_id`. I thought it is the user_id column in my database, but just set it to some random numbers (or string) and it works.

Sorry if it is a duplicate question or has already answered.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden this is not wp_login, it's the password hashing function.

Answer (score 2):

`wp-includes/pluggable.php` contains this function. The `user_id` argument is used twice:

```
if ( $check && $user_id ) {
    // Rehash using new hash.
    wp_set_password($password, $user_id);
    $hash = wp_hash_password($password);
}
```

This piece will set a users password if the passwords entered match. This is useful if you install a plugin that changes the password hashing mechanics, because it will migrate any passwords entered to the new mechanism when a user logs in.

This is, for instance, used by [roots wp-password-bcrypt plugin](https://github.com/roots/wp-password-bcrypt).

The second line occurs twice, but both times with a `return` statement:

```
return apply_filters( 'check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id );
```

This simply lets you catch that a password was just checked and, if needed, modify the result of the check.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot get the idea. If the password matches, what's the point to modify this password? Or, if an additional plugin changes the password hashing, how the password will match?

Comment: Old hashes will continue to work, it is however the responsibility of the plugin to make sure they do. Bcrypt hashes contain meta information at the start anyway, no idea how other types are detected (length?), but they are.

Comment: Another question: if I check the `$password` with, say the `$hash` of `userId = 1` (which matched), and I give the parameter `userId = 2`, does it change the parameter for `userId = 2` to the `$password`.

Comment: Yes. This function is not meant to be called directly, it is invoked in a chain from `wp-login`